# Why weird PIDs in kernel space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, pid

I have to hack the kernel scheduler for class.  I need to switch from my current TGID (2817) to its' sibling (2818).

I'm in my copy of pick_next_rt_entity (from rt.c) with Current TGID:PID  2817:2822.

My process tree looks like:

```
bash(2804)─┬─mylocT(2817)─┬─{mylocT}(2820)
           │              ├─{mylocT}(2821)
           │              └─{mylocT}(2822)
           ├─mylocT(2818)───{mylocT}(2823)
           └─pstree(2819)
```

My code looks like:

```
task = current->parent;
printk(KERN_INFO "\nCase 2 : PARENT CHILDREN: %s TGID %d", task->comm, task->tgid);
list_for_each(list,&task->children) {
    task1=list_entry(list,struct task_struct,children);
    printk(KERN_ALERT"\nPARENT THREAD GROUP: %s\tpid %d\ttgid %d \n",task1->comm,task1->pid,task1->tgid);
}
```

But the DMESG output looks like:

Entering for Current TGID:PID  2817:2822

```
[  182.486117] 
[  182.486117] Case 2 : PARENT CHILDREN: bash TGID 2804<1>[  182.486118] 
[  182.486118] PARENT THREAD GROUP:     pid 1149585120  tgid -30720 
[  182.486119] 
[  182.486119] PARENT THREAD GROUP:     pid 1149585120  tgid -30720 
[  182.486120] 
[  182.486120] PARENT THREAD GROUP:     pid 1149585120  tgid -30720 
[  182.486121]
```

Why am I getting bogus TGID/PID for the Parent's Children?

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect the tgid value in the kernel is the global ID and that, due to namespaces, it needs to be translated. I'm thinking you probably want `task_tgid_vnr(task)` to match up with user space.

Comment: You should use `sibling` instead of `children` in `list_entry`.